# ASP.NET MVC Postbacks and HtmlHelper Controls is not reflecting Model Changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm facing problems with a MVC5 Razor web application. I have an authentication page (cshtml) that has an Id and password helper controls:

```
@model NetInfinity.Middleware.VistaModelos.LoginVistaModelo
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h1>@Login.Acceso</h1>
        <p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Id, new { @placeholder = @Login.Usuario, autofocus = "", autocomplete = "off", maxlength = "15", size = "15" })
        </p>
        <p class="p1">
            @Html.PasswordFor(c => c.Clave, new { @placeholder = @Login.Contraseña, maxlength = "20", size = "20" })
            @Html.ActionLink(".", "Cambiopwd", null, new { @class = "login-cambiarpwd", id = "Cambiopwd" })
        </p>
        <p class="login-recordarpwd">@Html.ActionLink(@Login.RecordarPwd, "Recordatoriopwd")</p>
        <button type="button" class="login-submit" id="login-submit">@Login.LoginSubmit</button>
}
```

And the respective Model:

```
public class LoginVistaModelo
    {
        public string Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Clave
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string MensajeError
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

And Controller Action that validates user is:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginVistaModelo vmUsuario)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                EntidadesBD backend;
                var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
                backend = (EntidadesBD)cache.Get("backend");

                if (backend == null)
                {
                    backend = new EntidadesBD();
                    var politica = new CacheItemPolicy { Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable };
                    cache.Set("backend", backend, politica);
                }

                Usuario usuario = vmUsuario.ValidaUsuario();

                if (usuario == null)
                {
                    vmUsuario.MensajeError = "error2";
                    vmUsuario.Id = vmUsuario.Clave = String.Empty; // <--- This not works
                    ModelState.Clear(); // <-- This not works
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }

            return View(vmUsuario);
        }
```

When Login Action is triggered to validate user and password and error is thrown, I need to clear TextBoxFor value and PasswordFor value, and to achieve this I set model properties Id and Clave to string.empty in Controller, however when page (cshtml) is rendered again, controls keep old values ignoring model changes, not even if ModelState.Clear(). I've heard that HtmlHelpers controls (like .TextBoxFor() etc.) don't bind to model values on Postback, but rather get their value directly out of the POST buffer from ModelState. Please, ¿How can I do to update controls value when they are changed in Model properties?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do.  Why do you want to clear the values when there is an error?  It's better usability to keep the values so users can see what error they made.  Otherwise they may continue to make the same error.

Comment: because I want to force user to provide user and password again

Comment: That is terrible usability.  Particularly when you think about users who are using a touch device like a phone.  It may take considerable effort to enter the username with multiple keyboard transitions to various numbers and characters.  I absolutely hate websites like that.

Comment: Solution is an intranet oriented and not device nor phone uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try making the value of model null before returning it to view, 
like vmUsuario.id = null, vmUsuario.clave= null ;  and thn return the empty model to view

Answer (score 0):

A better approach for this type of problem would be to redirect the user, rather than returning the view.  Otherwise you run into the problem that if they press F5 it reposts the data.  So simply redirect the user, and use TempData to include your error message.  In your Get method, check if TempData contains an error message and display it if it does.